# Is this the correct way to interpret the Counter method in Python

Tags: python, counter

I'm starting to learn abut the Counter method and I wanted to confirm my knowledge with an example.

If the code is:

```c
note1 = "hello"
note2 = "world"
note1_counter = Counter(note1)
note1_counter = Counter(note2)
for i in note1:
      if note1_counter[i] > note2_counter[i]:
           # this line means if the number of times the letter at index i 
           # appears in note1 is larger than the number of times the same 
           # letter appears in note2 right?
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop:

```
for i in note1:
```

`i` is each *letter* in `note1` (that is, `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`), not each *index* in `note1` (which would be `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`).

This works out fine because the keys of your `Counter` objects are letters, not their corresponding indices in the original words.

So the line:

```
    if note1_counter[i] > note2_counter[i]:
```

is testing whether each letter `i` appears more frequently in `note1` than in `note2`.  It will trigger for the letter `l` (once for each time it occurs in `note1`).

Comment: > It will trigger for the letter l (once for each time it occurs in note1).

so it might make more sense to loop over the keys in `note1_counter` instead of the letters in `note1`; that way, you don't print out the fact that `l` shows up more twice.